# Soundcloud API throttling.

Tags: soundcloud

I am currently experimenting with the SoundCloud API, and have noticed that my GET requests for the /tracks resource never return more than 200 results at one time. A few questions about this:

1. Is this limit intentional?
2. Is there a way to increase this limit?
3. If not, what is the best way to work around this? is there an easy way to get some sort of continuation/pagination parameter, so that if more than 200 tracks match my query, I can issue a new query to get the next set of matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pagination](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/introduction#pagination) from the API documentation. Try passing in `limit` and `offset` parameters. The max for `limit` is 200 and the max for `offset` is 8000.