# soundcloud-python uploading a track is extremely slow

Tags: python, django, heroku, soundcloud

I am uploading tracks to SoundCloud using the soundcloud-python api wrapper (https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python).

Everything is working correctly, but uploading a track to SoundCloud takes about 1 minute per megabyte (e.g. invoking client.post('/tracks', track=data) with a 45 MB mp3 file is taking about 45 minutes to upload).

I have verified that I can push data at Gbps speed from this server (it's a worker dyno on Heroku) to other servers over the internet. Does SoundCloud throttle the API for uploading data or are there settings I can tweak that will help improve the speed?

Here is sample code:

```
import soundcloud
client = soundcloud.Client(access_token='OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN')
res = client.post('/tracks',
                  track={'title': 'my title',
                         'asset_data':open('file.mp3', 'rb') 
                        }
                 )
```

Comment: If the remote host is throttling its download rate, I wouldn't know what you can do about it.

Comment: Just updating this to note that it is a confirmed issue with SoundCloud, that the throttling is not by design, and that it seems to affect some networks but not others.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your code is sending packets that are being selectively filtered out by your router? As Niklas B. mentioned above, the remote host could be limiting the rate. Have you contacted Soundcloud? Try uploading a file from your server through the standard Soundcloud interface and clocking that transfer rate.

Also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668311/soundcloud-api-throttling), 
asked Mar 12 at 13:52 by user1264242

Comment: Thanks for the ideas technohazard. It doesn't appear to be a router issue on my end, as I can push data very quickly using the python network modules to other locations. StackOverflow is Soundcloud's official support forum so I'm hoping someone will chime in. I'll have a look at posting to their web interface and see what I get.