# Soundcloud API Pagination - does the offset limit of 8000 mean you can't get the entirety of a list over 8000 in length?

Tags: javascript, pagination, soundcloud

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve a list of 60k+ followers through pagination. Right now, this is how I'm doing it (I'm guessing this could be syntactically better):

```js
var array = [];
var page_length = 200;
var num_pages = 40;
var offset = 0;   

for (i=0; i< num_pages; i++) {
     SC.get("/users/" + id + "/followers", {limit: page_length, offset: offset},
          function(followers) {
               for (j=0; j < page_length; j++) {
                    array.push(followers[j]);
               }
               if(array[array.length-1] != undefined && array.length == page_length * num_pages) {
                    //success    
               }
          }
          );
    offset+=page_length;
}
```

I have the `page_length` set at the maximum of 200 according to the API documentation. If I increase the `num_pages` to, for example, 45, the resulting `followers[]` array for that iteration only contains undefined records, because `num_pages*page_length` will exceed the 8000 offset limit.

So is there any way to get more than 8000 records into this array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668311/soundcloud-api-throttling

Comment: @Timmerz im aware of these limits. that user was trying to get more than 200 out of one request. I'm just curious why there wouldn't be a practical way to retrieve a result set exceeding 8000....seems impractical

Comment: based on his answer in that thread it looks like 8000 is the max offset. I'm not familiar with the soundcloud api, but I assume they don't want to serve large amounts of data via the api.

Comment: @Timmerz yea thats what I'm afraid of. I wonder if there is another way to retrieve this large list. maybe through a screen scraper or something...

Comment: what is your use case? 60k is quite a lot of data to serve via an api. let's say they had some with 1M+? what is your limit? see what I'm saying? you'd probably just overload their api.

Comment: @Timmerz right and I do understand that for sure. In my usage, the user enters a username, and the request will get all of the followers for that user. I just wish I could at least break up the 60k into spaced out requests of 8000. I at least wish there was a way to retrieve, for example, the second chunk of 8000 followers and only that chunk... What if you want the first 200 followers that ever followed a user? with the API the way it is, it seems you couldn't because the request will only get the latest 200. any ideas?

Comment: I would advise to just not get the individual followers. maybe just return the total count. I can see how you could quickly thrash soundcloud to death with your use case.

Comment: @Timmerz yea i can see that...

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch out, SoundCloud just "updated" their API and after March 3rd you won't be able to use the API with an "offset" parameter. You have to change your code to be working properly in the future.

So at first, the SoundCloud API has set the limit to 50 by default and you can set the limit to 200 (maximum).

Second thing is - after you send a request, your response usually contains a "next_href" cursor, which you have to call to get the next e.g. 200 followers. SoundCloud now changed that. If you don't add the "linked_partitioning" parameter to your URL, you will only get the first 200 followers. If you add the parameter, you get the *next_href*.

I don't get why you set num_pages to 40? In your case, i would fetch 200 followers, put them in my array. Then use the *next_href* - cursor to fetch the next 200 followers (and so on ...). If there is no *next_href* in the response, then there aren't any followers left.

In JavaScript it would look like this I think:

```js
var page_size = 200;

SC.get("/users/" + id + "/followers", { limit: page_size, linked_partitioning: 1 }, function(followers) {
  // do your stuff here with every 200 followers (as long as there are followers)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this but I've managed to get it working with a click event on a 'next' button, like this:

```js
var nextCursor;

function next() {
  SC.get('/users/' + userId + '/followers', {

    limit: 200,
    linked_partitioning: 1,
    cursor: nextCursor

  }).then(function(followers) {

    var nextHref = followers.next_href;
    nextCursor = nextHref.substr(nextHref.length - 13);

    $(followers.collection).each(function(i) {

      console.log(followers.collection[i])

    });
  });
}

$("#next-btn").click(function() {
  next();
});
```

I'm now trying to improve this so that one click of a 'search' button would return all followers.

The closest I've got is setting the page limit to 100, dividing the total followers by 100 and storing it in a variable (so that I can increment by 1 in a loop - I know this isn't ideal but it will serve for the moment) and then wrapping the GET request in a while loop where 'x' is less than the total followers. However, this only returns the first page of results as the 'nextCursor' variable never updates.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this might be possible?

```js
var userId;
var totalFollowers;

function getUser() {

  SC.get('/users/' + userName, {}).then(function(user) {
    userId = user.id;
    totalFollowers = user.followers_count / 100;
  })

}

function getFollowers() {

  var x = 1;

  while (x < totalFollowers) {
    var nextCursor;
    SC.get('/users/' + userId + '/followers', {

      limit: 100,
      linked_partitioning: 1,
      cursor: nextCursor

    }).then(function(followers) {

      $(followers.collection).each(function(i) {

        var nextHref = followers.next_href;
        nextCursor = nextHref.substr(nextHref.length - 13);
        console.log(nextCursor)

      });
    });
    x++;
  }
}
```